# How to output a generated HTML string to a textbox without paragraph formating

Tags: c#, wpf

I am generating an HTML string in a WPF application, and I am outputting it to a multiline textbox. Right now the output is wrapping, but is showing up similar to a paragraph. I would like it to be shown as formatted HTML. It wouldn't even have to be very nice formatting, but at least not show a paragraph of HTML.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Here is a .net wrapper for [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) [https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged](https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged)

Comment: We need more information on what formatting you want. Do you want rich text formatting like bold and italics? Do you want linebreaks inserted somewhere? If so, where? How many? Does your HTML string have tags in it to begin with?

Answer (score 12):

If your HTML is well-formed XML, then the `XElement.ToString()` method will format with indents and newlines:

```
try
{
    formattedOutput = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(myHtmlString).ToString();
}
catch
{
    // isn't well-formed xml
}
```

Comment: It will remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` from `HTML`

Comment: It crashes on unmatched tags like `<input>` or `<img>`

Comment: `If your HTML is well-formed XML` - what are the chances?!

Comment: @minseong Well-formed XML would imply you are using XHTML instead which would indicate closing tags like `<input />` and `<img />`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) package to accomplish this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a formatted version of the specified HTML text (which will presumably be unformatted - e.g. all on one line).
/// Uses the AngleSharp library/package.
/// </summary>
public static String FormatHtmlText(String htmlText)
{
    try
    {
        var parser = new AngleSharp.Html.Parser.HtmlParser();

        using var document = parser.ParseDocument(htmlText);

        using var sw = new StringWriter();

        var formatter = new AngleSharp.Html.PrettyMarkupFormatter { Indentation = "    ", NewLine = Environment.NewLine };

        document.ToHtml(sw, formatter);

        return sw.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        return htmlText;
    }
}
```

The `StringWriter` requires a `using System.IO;` statement at top.