# Format HTML through C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to format my html through C#. Here my example code.

`<div dir="ltr"><div class="gmail_quote"><strong><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;">CA IQVIA EM Event Speaker info</span></strong></div></div>`

I want to output like this :

```
`<div dir="ltr">
    <div class="gmail_quote">
       <strong>
        <span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;">
           CA IQVIA EM Event Speaker info
         </span>
        </strong>
    </div>
 </div>`
```

How Should I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service or a "how to" tutorial service. The objective here is for others to help you fix your code when it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680251/c-sharp-string-to-formatted-html-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need.

```
var input = "<div dir=\"ltr\"><div class=\"gmail_quote\"><strong><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;\">CA IQVIA EM Event Speaker info</span></strong></div></div>";

try
{
  var formatted = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(input).ToString();
}
catch
{
  // Your input is not a valid xml fragment.
}
```

Comment: Does it works??? Check -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/LGfxo1

Comment: Does it work?!!! Yes, run it somewhere other than the fiddle: http://rextester.com/PXRPB9022

Comment: Sure. It's works thanks for time.

Comment: it does not works for cshtml